# I have a single name written as my surname in passport, while my given name is blank, will the German Embassy accept this?

Tags: passports, schengen-visas, applications, pakistani-citizens

I live in Pakistan and I have the single name "sumayya". In my passport it is written in the surname column and my given name column is blank. I'm hoping to go to Germany in April for trade and exhibition. So will the German embassy accept my passport or not? I don't have many days to work this out as I have to submit my passport latest by 20th march.

Comment: Does the name on your passport correspond exactly with your birth certificate and any other official (eg government and/or state) records?

Comment: @Traveller Why would that matter?

Comment: @David Richerby I don’t know that it would - I was just wondering if the OP would be able to provide any other documentation regarding his identity if asked. I’ve seen a few questions where individuals have had problems due to discrepancies between official records, that’s what prompted my comment.

Comment: The duplicate question concerns people who say they have "only a first name and no surname," while sumayya reports having only one name, which is written in the passport as a surname.  It should be noted that the ICAO specification doesn't actually speak of "surname" and "first name" or similar terms, but of primary and secondary identifiers.  The surname or family name corresponds to the primary identifier, as does a single name (of course), so the passport mentioned here, listing the single name as the surname, is consistent with the international standard.